# bindtextdomain and .mo files

Tags: localization, locale, gettext

I have some question about this:

1) I am reading how .mo files work and i see that the folder of my locale need to be:
`/locale/de_DE/LC_MESSAGES/domainname.mo`

Wordpress and others have different path as: `/locale/de_DE.mo` `/locale/it_IT.mo` etc.
How can I set the second strategy?

2) in `setlocale()` can O use something else other than `it_IT`, `de_DE`? I want use [this](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-2). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. It is internal process of gettext. Gettext was designed for unix applications with localizations at /usr/locale/de_DE/LC_MESSAGES/domain.mo. It made sense that way. On PHP I believe it does not make sense.. And as many people before, I spent time wondering what do I wrong. Because on some platforms, de_DE and it_IT are wrong, on some they are right. See [PHP/Gettext Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398113/php-gettext-problems) or [PHP gettext on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473207/php-gettext-on-windows) .

If you will accept my recommendation, I suggest you stick to gettext files, but use other than default PHP gettext backend. Good and simple is https://launchpad.net/php-gettext/. More powerfull might be Zend Translator, but you need big framework for that. I recommend you stay away from PHP gettext module.